# Loading Animation CSS for Carousel Header

Tags: css, slider, styles, css-animations, carousel

Anyone got an idea how to create a header slider with such an animation: https://chadwickdesigns.com.au/ ?

Comment: https://smartslider3.com/blog/animations-effects-smart-slider-3/

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy load animation to slider

```
$(".carousel.lazy").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(ev) {
var lazy;
lazy = $(ev.relatedTarget).find("img[data-src]");
if(lazy.length > 0){

  $("#loader_container").css("visibility","visible");
  $(".carousel-item img").on("load",function(){
    $("#loader_container").css("visibility","hidden");
  });

  lazy.attr("src", lazy.data('src'));
  lazy.removeAttr("data-src");
}});
```